# How to change z-index value on hoverization?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the value of z-index on hoverisation for which I have writtn the following code. 
My html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"> The first link </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="http://www.github.com"> the second link</a>
        </div>
</html>
```

My CSS is here:

```
div:first-child a
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size:20px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:green;
}

div + div a
{
    font-size:20px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    left:50% ;
    background-color: red;
}

div:first-child a:hover
{
    z-index:555555; 
    font-size:10px;
}

div + div a:hover
{
    z-index:555555;
    font-size:50px;
}
```

On hovering only font-size is changing. How can I do it using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

add

```
position:relative;
```

to your other divs.

z-index only works with elements that have been explicitly given position.

Comment: If I want to put one div over the another,how is it possible without using position value absolute?

Comment: thing is that z-index only works if you set any kind of position. set it to relative/fixed/absolute/static/ doesnt matter, but you have to set a position. only then z-index will work.

Answer (score 0):

This can be work for you

`div:first-child a`
`{
    position: relative;
    font-size:20px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: (give value);
    background-color:green;
}`

Comment: z-index: (give value); I couldnot get it?

Comment: Ok I got it.I can give any value.